# TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialPreferences' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm facing this issue :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialPreferences' of undefined

> 1 | import { Appearance } from 'react-native-appearance';
> | ^
> 2 |
> 3 | export const modedColor = (lightModeColor, darkModeColor) => {
> 4 |   return Appearance.getColorScheme() === 'dark'

at Object. (node_modules/react-native-appearance/lib/commonjs/index.tsx:15:1)
at Object. (src/Core/helpers/colors.js:1:1)

Thanks you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

run pod install in ios directory
delete app from device/emulator
in xcworkspace , clean build folder & run

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31394697)